# Careers cannot import LinkedIn

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linkedin

I recently checked out my Careers account and I was in the process of importing data from other services, such as Github and LinkedIn. The account was created in April 2013.

However, when trying to authorize Careers to access my LinkedIn data, I was given the following error message:

> U moet een bevestigd e-mailadres opgeven om verder te kunnen gaan.

This (roughly) translates to:

> You need to provide a confirmed e-mail address to continue.

My LinkedIn profile has two e-mail addresses linked to it, both of which have been verified.

I am not sure if my Careers e-mail address has been verified, because I can not find any e-mails sent from Careers containing a verification link. However, there is also no indication (in both e-mail as on the website) that my e-mail address has not yet been verified. However, because the verification process happens on LinkedIn's domain, I doubt the verification of my Careers account would even matter.

I also realize that this issue might be LinkedIn's doing, but it is preventing the import feature on Careers from working for me. Therefore, I am reporting this bug here.

Has anyone else ever had this issue?
How do I check the status of my Careers credentials (to see if they're verified)?

Comment: Is this issue specific to Stack Overflow?

Comment: I do not know, I have no other profiles on other websites with LinkedIn imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I found a workaround.

When the oauth page loads, it already contains your profile image and some minor data if you're logged in to LinkedIn. There is an option "not you?" to switch the account you want to import.

Click this link to log out, and then log back in using the oauth form.